# Raw fish pieces have stuck to each other in freezer. How to take out few pieces of fish without disturbing other pieces?

Tags: freezing, fish

Raw fish pieces have stuck to each other in freezer. How to take out few pieces of fish without disturbing other pieces?

Thawing whole bunch may not make sense since I do not intend to eat them all today. What are my options?

My question is about "how" to do it. Should I hammer out the pieces without thawing them? If yes, then what would be the approach to do it?

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40690/6168

> Quick and sloppy:
>
> Pry the frozen fillets apart using a case knife or use a wedge of some sort to separate them physically without thawing.

Why is this method called sloppy? What is wrong with it?

Comment: See also: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/39963/can-i-defrost-chicken-to-separate-then-refreeze. The same principles apply here.

Comment: @Jolenealaska I have edited the question. I want to know how to proceed with separating the piece.

Comment: BTW, The close vote isn't mine. My best answer to your issue is the answer to the question I linked, but others may have better advice.

Comment: Here's another question that might be of help: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40152/how-do-i-separate-two-fish-fillets-that-have-been-frozen-together?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only best option is complete thaw to get them in good shape and in one piece, but that is not an option for you.

Next one up is the quick and sloppy method. But it will distroy the shape of the fish, hence the name.

**My tip: Wrap the pieces of fish in a cling film/kitchen foil individually next time before freezing. That will most certainly allow you to take a few pieces out without thawing or using knife/wedge etc.**

Answer (score 3):

Do NOT pry frozen foods, in particular of odd shapes like fish or chicken apart with a knife. That is a recipe for deep laceration wounds. (I’ve treated many, including through nerves and tendons.)
Instead, put all the fish in a plastic bag, or two, full a deep container with cold water, and soak only the section which protrudes, and is about the size you can use. Cut the semi-thawed section off as soon as able, and return remainder to freezer asap.

Answer (score 2):

There is always the percussion method. In a thick plastic bag, repeatedly bang the pieces of fish etc. on a hard worktop along the seam where the pieces join. The smaller pieces of ice holding the pieces together should fracture, allowing the bigger pieces to separate. I have used this method with square sausages, hamburgers etc.

As Hannah has stated, trying to pry frozen food apart is a recipe for a visit to hospital.